# Qual o significado da declaração do operador de multiplicação duas vezes?

Tags: php, operadores, matemática, números

Como funciona o operador de multiplicação quando declarado duas vezes, por exemplo:

```
$valor = 10**5;
```

Comment: Funciona como operador Exponencial: 10 elevado a 5 potência

Comment: '**' não é multiplicação é potenciação. Veja [Operadores Aritméticos](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.arithmetic.php).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Funciona como operador *Exponencial*

O operador de exponencial é usado quando queremos elevar algum valor a potência, este operador é representado no PHP por ( * * ) (Dois Asterisco).

> O Operador Exponencial foi introduzido no PHP a partir da versão 5.6.

```
<?php
  $num1 = 10;
  $num2 = 2;
  
  // 10*10
  $potencia = $num1 ** $num2;
  
  echo $potencia;
  
  /* O resultado exibido é => 100 */
```

No caso do seu exemplo, 10 elevado a 5 `10**5` ficaria:

```
10*10*10*10*10 = ‭100.000‬
```